# Resume Header (Place name and program beside contacts)

Tags: cv

I am trying to make a resume header like the one shown below:
[image]

This is what I have so far:
[image]

I do not know how to put my name and program beside my contacts.
My name and program are on separate lines.
My contacts are placed in a table (1 column, 3 rows, the text is left justified).

So my code looks something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%======PREAMBLE======================
% Document font - https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/gillius?lang=en
\usepackage{gillius}

% Add clickable links
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Set spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

% Use Font Awesome icons
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{xparse}

%====================================
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}

% HEADER

% Name & Program
\begin{flushleft}
Anthony Johnson \\*
Electrical Engineering Student at MIT
\end{flushleft}

% Contacts Section
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{ l } 
 \href{https://github.com/AnthonyJohnson}{\faGithub \hspace{0.25 em} AnthonyJohnson} \\
 \href{mailto:ajohnson@mit.com}{\faEnvelope \hspace{0.25 em} ajohnson@mit.com} \\
 \faPhone \hspace{0.25 em} (123) - 456 - 7890 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
\end{onehalfspacing}
```

Could someone please tell me how I can accomplish this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use two minipages like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%======PREAMBLE======================
% Document font - https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/gillius?lang=en
\usepackage{gillius}

% Set spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

% Use Font Awesome icons
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Add clickable links
\usepackage{hyperref}

\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}

% HEADER

% Name & Program
\noindent % <===========================================================
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth} % <==================================
\begin{flushleft}
Anthony Johnson \\*
Electrical Engineering Student at MIT
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage} % <======================================================
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.35\textwidth}% <==================================
% Contacts Section
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{ l } 
 \href{https://github.com/AnthonyJohnson}{\faGithub \hspace{0.25 em} AnthonyJohnson} \\
 \href{mailto:ajohnson@mit.com}{\faEnvelope \hspace{0.25 em} ajohnson@mit.com} \\
 \faPhone \hspace{0.25 em} (123) - 456 - 7890 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}% <=======================================================

\end{document}
```

to get the wished result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have two more questions, how come the resume looks different if I add blank lines before and after the "\hfill" command. Also, is there anything that I should fix with what I have so far like syntax, etc.

Comment: I am currently using faEnvelope, but I want to use faEnvelope[regular]. However, the sizes don't seem to be the same. So the text does not look align with the other text. How can I fix this? Thx :)

Comment: We do not like "Living Questions" here, i.e. asking more questions in comments. Instead please ask a new question, add relevant TeX  code and describe your new problem ... And do not forget to upvote and accept the most helpful answer ...